# Telegram Bots APIs - forward_from

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm tring to acces the id of a user by a forwarded message but the value is always null, even if they don't have privacy of forwarded messages enabled, am I doing something wrong?

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$forwardFrom = $update['forward_from']['id'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$update['message']['forward_from']['id'];
```